# How do I change the name displayed underneath my app icon on my device's Home screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle, application-name

I'm trying to change my app name which is displayed with icon on my device's home screen in iOS.
Every post says this can be done by changing string in "Bundle display name" in App's Info.list file.
But it didn't work for me. I've changed my "project name","target name" and "This Bundle display name". None of these helped me.

When I check the bundle display name on running app with following code it shows the updated name. But the app name is still remained.

```
NSLog(@"APP NAME : %@",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"]);
```

BTW, My app has been created around 4-5 years ago and I've been trying to change the app name recently.

Can you guys help me? It doesn't matter any possible solution or suggestion.
Please let me know if you guys need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the plist file if you have in some place the old name? And check also in the project properties .

Comment: @Lorenzo Yeah, I tried to search with my old app name in "plist" or "build setting" But I was not able to find it. That's very weird I can't find my old app name but the app name show as old name. Where came it from??

Answer (score 5):

You can change the name of the App displaying in Home Screen by changing the [Bundle Display Name](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html) in Info.plist or if you need to change the Build product name then change

> Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name.

Comment: Are you saying The Product Name under Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name? If it is.. I've already changed it but it didn't work. ;(

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same target which you have edited?

Comment: Yes, I have only 2 targets. One is App target and the other one is Unit Test Target.

Comment: @Tommy Uninstall app from device or clear simulator if you'r using it and clear the project (In Xcode, `Product menu -> Clean`)

Comment: Did you try changing Bundle name in info.plist of your project?

Comment: Check this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html . The procedure is to change Bundle Display Name to change display name and product name to change the product output name

Comment: @psci I did it in the past but it didn't help me.

Comment: @abyt07 Yeah, I tried to change Bundle name in info.plist of my project.

Comment: @abyt07 I did it before ask this to here. But thank you very much for it.

Comment: Just try removing the Derived data and reseting the Simulator. It may be some issue in replacing the new compiled build in Simulator.

Comment: @abyt07 I'm testing on my device. :(

Answer (score 1):

Refer below image:
[image]

Suppose that if you want to install same app again with different name then change bundle id.

Comment: Thanks I also changed Product Name where exactly same place with the picture you've attached. But it didn't help. But Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Comment: May i know the Xcode version the project created? (BTW, My app has been created around 4-5 years). I am using this from xcode 4.0 to Xcode 7 and it works well

Comment: I guess it was Xcode 4.x or something. I've developed it with iOS4SDK and sure I've updating since I've first released it. Do you need exact Xcode number? Do you know how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Info.plist-> Bundle name replace completely with your desired it works when you run the app.

Comment: Thanks, But it didn't help. I guess my project setting is somehow broken. Changing app name works well when I try to change app name with the project which is just created by the latest Xcode but mine was created around 4-5 years ago. I wonder this caused some problem.

Comment: I got same old app name. But when I try to search with the old app name on "Build setting" search field, I can't find any matches keyword with old app name. It's really weird. Where the old app name is coming from??

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it in Xcode7:

1. Click tour project in Project navigator

[image]

2. Open the utilities tab (on the right side) and change the name

[image]

3. Wizzard will appear

[image]

4. Click rename. Done.

It's always a good practice to make backup somehow (git or  project snap shoot) before renaming project :)

Comment: These steps not required to change only the display name, simply change the build settings as suggested in other solutions.

Comment: @psci Thank you for the very kind explanation. But I already did it when I change my project name.

Comment: @GobiM you can always uncheck option you don't want to rename in wizard.

Comment: This method will make things **stop working** if there exists a bridging header file already, because it changes the app name completely!